# How to disable cache in Windows 10 on the Edge browser?

Tags: browser-cache, microsoft-edge, no-cache

How to disable or delete browser cache in Windows 10 on the Edge browser?

There are no options on preferences and developer tools (F12)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Open Developer Tools <del>then cache is disabled automatically.</del> And click "Network" tab then click "Always refresh from server" button.
(It only works if the Developer Tools is open)

Comment: Same for Windows 11. For me its just called "Disable cache".

Answer (score 8):

Just open Network and click on the selected icon (in the image). It will not cache till the dev tools are open.

[image: Screenshot of dev tools]

Comment: This is the same as the answer from July of 2015.

Comment: It's true that the answers give the same solution, but I think that the screenshot makes this one more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In all edge shortcut properties (including system) add:

`--disk-cache-dir=nul`

and clear manually folders:

```
c:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cache\
c:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Code Cache\
```

Now disk cache disable. usefull on ssd disks and working with: Chromium / Google Chrome / Opera / Edge

Answer (score 0):

With so many of the functions from VS Code working seamlessly and automatically the repeated manual selection in Edge to turn off caching is really disappointing. For Chrome, I find the following works.

Python 3.11.4, aiohttp 3.8.5 and angular 16 using websockets.

1. Run my webserver, serving pages from dist/angular_project.
2. `ng build --configuration development --watch`
3. From command prompt `start chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-application-cache`
4. Within VSCode ...

```
    {
      "name": "chrome python",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222
    },
```

1. In the debug chrome window, open the connection to the python webserver.
2. In VSCode run the debug config in 4: above.
3. Set my breakpoints, python, angular, where-ever ... works
   I suffer a lot less weird *why are my edits missing from my code* headscratching (yes, user error :P ).

Maybe this works for Edge. It's so hard to find command line switches for Edge I just couldn't be bothered trying. YMMV.